# Unity3d official sdk FB.UI

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-sdk-3.0, facebook-unity-sdk

In the documentation there is a page describing this method: [FB.UI](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/reference/FB.UI/)

I downloaded this plugin, there are other methods like `FB.AppRequest`, `FB.Init`, `FB.Feed`,
But no `FB.UI`.
Isn't it implemented yet?

Answer (score 1):

FB.UI is very canvas specific and is also redundant with other calls in the SDK, it supports the following dialogs on canvas:

- The Feed Dialog: FB.Feed
- The OAuth Dialog: Call FB.Login with the permissions you want. Even once a user is logged in, just call FB.Login again if you want new permissions.
- The Friends/Request Dialog: FB.AppRequest
- The Pay Dialog: FB.Canvas.Pay (canvas only)
- The Send Dialog: not supported
- Add Page Tab Dialog: not supported

The not supported options can still be accessed by calling out to javascript on canvas.

Comment: So if I use this plugin from unity android, I can't use those options?
Or how can i access them?